# CSS Specificity, Why different properties generate different outcome?

Tags: css

[Picture of the CSS Styling issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd1WK.png)

I'm trying hard time as a beginner to understand this phenomena but I just don't get it. How a color property can be more specific at the same time as a border can be less specific, when the conflict is happening within the same selectors. To my understanding the shorthands wins inside the header, why and always? That is something I really want to understand. This has become an inspection to me.
Sorry for not getting it.

Auto generated answer from GPT:
*In the case of conflicts between a global attribute and a div for the border property and the color property, the div will win for both properties.

This is because the border property has a higher specificity than the global attribute selector, but a lower specificity than the div selector. Therefore, if there is a conflict, the div selector will take precedence.

Similarly, the color property has a higher specificity when defined in the global attribute selector, but a lower specificity than when defined in the div selector. Therefore, if there is a conflict, the div selector will take precedence.*

I expected that all the global attribute within the same conflict would generate the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cascade, specificity, and inheritance

Please go through [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#understanding_inheritance) about **cascade, specificity, and inheritance**.

> There are three factors to consider, listed here in increasing order
> of importance. Later ones overrule earlier ones:
>
> - Source order
> - Specificity
> - Importance

The reasoning behind this is because the global selector attributes (`*`) are more specific than attributes of `header`. And because "hellos" is most likely wrapped in an element, as well as links (only guesstimation, since no code was provided), the following code is applied only to the `header` element itself, not its children:

```
header {
    color: red;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

On the image you attached properties are inherited by the **specificity** rule. However, if you try the code below, you can observe that its properties are expanded to all the elements contained by the `header` element:

```
header * {
    color: red;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Why has the border changed color then? Wouldn't that also apply to the same rule, that the global attribute has higher specificity, why is it now reversed?

Comment: @user21781739 as it was mentioned in answer, the border color was applied because the `header` element has attributes that are applied to the `header` element itself. However, for its children, attributes of the global selector `*` were applied. Therefore the hierarchy is the following: `html` and `body` inherited `*` attributes, `header` has its own attributes (red border), children of `header` inherited `*` attributes (have yellow borders).

Comment: After reading it over a couple of times it starting to make some sense. =) Thanks for explaining